# Thread pooling when a Stateless EJB is injected in a Webservice which has been annotated as a Singleton

Tags: java, web-services, singleton, ejb-3.1

I am reviewing some code and have some questions regarding the implementation. This class is exposed as a web service and annotated as a singleton. A stateless EJB is injected into this class. This is what the code looks like:

```
@Singleton
@Webservice
public class AImpl implements A, ARemote {
    :
    :
    @EJB
    private B b;

    @WebMethod
    public String someWebService(){

         String value = this.b.someMethod();
         return value;
    }

}
```

Here is the definition of B:

```
@Local
public interface B {
    public String someMethod();
}


@Stateless(mappedName="B")
public class BImpl implements B, BRemote {
   public String someMethod() {
    // do something
   }
}
```

My Question:
Since the webservice is a Singleton, there will be only one instance. There will be only one thread (Please correct me if I am wrong here). Though B is capable of having a thread pool, as it is stateless, does it matter as the webservice from which it is called is a Singleton.

I am learning EJB concepts currently. Any input/clarifications to my understanding will help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, singleton EJBs are `@ConcurrencyManagement(CONTAINER)` and methods are `@Lock(WRITE)`, so you're right that methods on your singleton bean can only be called from a single thread. However, if you use `@ConcurrencyManagement(BEAN)` or `@Lock(READ)`, then this would no longer be true.  Anyway, in your example, if the singleton session bean is the only caller of `BImpl`, then even if your EJB server implements pooling for stateless session beans, it will only ever need to create one instance.

(Note that while stateless session beans can have an *instance* pool, they do not have a *thread* pool. The application server might use a thread pool for inbound requests, but they are not directly associated with the stateless session bean or related instances.)